# Is there a library function in Python to turn a generator-function into a function returning a list?

Tags: python, generator

A number of times I've thought that generator style can be more direct that returning a list, for example,

```
def foo(input_array):
    for x in input_array:
        yield processed(x)
```

vs.

```
def bar(input_array):
    accumulator = []
    for x in input_array:
        accumulator.append(processed(x))
    return accumulator
```

(okay, if it were really that simple, I'd write `map`, but you get the point: the generator version is cleaner). However, a return type of a generator is not always desired. Is there a built-in decorator that I can use to change `foo` into a function returning a list or tuple? The way I'd write it myself is,

```
import functools

def transform_return_value(transformer):
    def inner(f):
        @functools.wraps(f)
        def new_f(*argv, **kwargs):
            return transformer(f(*argv, **kwargs))
        return new_f
    return inner

@transform_return_value(list)
def foo(input_array):
    for x in input_array:
        yield processed(x)
```

Comment: Wait ... You want to write a generator function that returns a list?  I'm not sure I understand this.  Why not just write `list(generator_function())`, or write `list_function()` to begin with?

Comment: Another choice is to use list comprehension: `[processed(x) for x in input_array]`. Arguably cleaner than both...

Comment: @mgilson is right: usually you'd convert to list when you need a list, which is invariably in the client code. I tend to document functions as returning iterables and keep a `to_sequence(x)` function around that effectively does `list(x) if not isinstance(x, Sequence) else x`.

Comment: It seems like some people are missing the point of this question… And since it's a question I've had in the past, let me try to clarify: “there are situations where a function can be more cleanly *implemented* as a generator, but the function is required to *return* a `list`.” Obviously there are many sensible ways to write a function which returns a list. But OP is specifically interested in *decorating functions which return a generator* so that it it will return a list.

Comment: @DavidWolever -- as far as implementation is concerned, `yield ...` -> `lst.append(...)`.  That doesn't seem much easier to me ...

Comment: @mgilson that is definitely a valid point. But that's not the point being addressed by the comments and answers. The comments and answers seemed to be focused different methods for “getting a list” (ex, generator expressions, wrapping calls to the function in `list(…)`)… Not answering the OP's *actual question*: “is there a library function in Python to turn a generator-function into a function returning a list?”.

Comment: If I seem a bit frustrated, it's because I've often been in a position similar to the OP: I've described clear constraints and asked a specific question… But instead of getting answers to that question, I've been told that my constraints are wrong. Which, while understandable (“you're asking the wrong question” is definitely a valid answer to some questions), can be very frustrating.

Comment: @DavidWolever, Thanks for your defense. The reason I want to do it this way is so that callee code doesn't have to be cluttered with list(foo(...)) calls, since those are ugly. And, to address mgilson's remark, I tagged the question with 'aesthetics' and made it clear I prefer less imperative code (list.append, etc.). (And, though orthogonal, there is the point that the generator/decorator scheme makes it easier to switch to tuples, if one wanted immutability).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge (and I've looked, because I've wondered exactly the same thing), no: there is no direct way of doing this with the standard library.

There is a thoroughly tested `listify` wrapper in unstdlib.py library, though: https://github.com/shazow/unstdlib.py/blob/master/unstdlib/standard/list_.py#L149

```
def listify(fn=None, wrapper=list):
    """
    A decorator which wraps a function's return value in ``list(...)``.

    Useful when an algorithm can be expressed more cleanly as a generator but
    the function should return an list.

    Example::

        >>> @listify
        ... def get_lengths(iterable):
        ...     for i in iterable:
        ...         yield len(i)
        >>> get_lengths(["spam", "eggs"])
        [4, 4]
        >>>
        >>> @listify(wrapper=tuple)
        ... def get_lengths_tuple(iterable):
        ...     for i in iterable:
        ...         yield len(i)
        >>> get_lengths_tuple(["foo", "bar"])
        (3, 3)
    """
    def listify_return(fn):
        @wraps(fn)
        def listify_helper(*args, **kw):
            return wrapper(fn(*args, **kw))
        return listify_helper
    if fn is None:
        return listify_return
    return listify_return(fn)
```

Comment: "my library of tools that I copy+paste around between projects" I don't know whether to feel relieved or dismayed that I am not the only one who does this. I have a handful of Python functions that seem to make it into most of my Python projects. Copying and pasting seems gross, but they're so small (and unrelated to one another) that putting them in a library seems like overkill.

Comment: Ah ha! Since writing this answer I've started exactly such a library: https://github.com/shazow/unstdlib.py

Comment: I'd rather call the decorator something like `wrap_return` then do `listify = wrap_return(wrapper=list)` instead of using `@listify(wrapper=Counter)`

Answer (score 8):

Although @David Wolever's answer is suerly the cleanest way, one thing I often find myself doing (as it doesn't require to define an external decorator) is writing the generator as a local function, like this:

```
def foo(input_array):
    def gen():
        for x in input_array:
            yield processed(x)

    return list(gen())
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an alternative, simple decorator without any bells and whistles:

```
from functools import wraps
from types import GeneratorType

def listify(func):
    """decorator for making generator functions return a list instead"""
    @wraps(func)
    def new_func(*args, **kwargs):
        r = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if isinstance(r, GeneratorType):
            return list(r)
        else:
            return r
    return new_func
```

Answer (score -6):

For efficient and concise list definitions try using list comprehension:

```
def foo(input_array):
    return [processed(x) for x in input_array]
```

**If you want a function to return a list, have it return a list.** This is much cleaner, easier to understand, read and debug than using decorator.

You may prefer to write this inline, rather than call a function.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. The OP is describing situations where it's cleaner to implement a function using a generator, but the return value of that function must be a list. In those situations, it's totally reasonable to implement a function as a generator, then wrap it in a decorator that unwraps that generator to a list.

Comment: @David And it's even cleaner to use list comprehension!

Comment: Yes, this *specific example* is cleaner as a list comprehension. But the question is not “how do I clean up the implementation of this function?”, the question is “Is there a library function in Python to turn a generator-function into a function returning a list?”

Comment: hayden: thank you for your willingness to help, but I made it clear that `foo` was just an example function (metavariable); for that actual implementation, I'd have written `map` (in the callee site), or `foo = functools.partial(map, processed)`, or `foo = lambda xs: map(processed, xs)` (which are more concise than list comprehensions...).